# how can i prevent the get url to show text or random text instead

Tags: php

eg, $search = $_GET[$id];

instead of showing website.com/result.php?find=56

it would be website.com/result.php?find=sometext

in the db 56 is the id and sometext is the title how can i get the title to show instead when i use the get url id function

Comment: Um... simply put text into the URL instead of the id...? What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can also use .htaccess redirection with something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^find/(.*)$ result.php?find=$1 [L,QSA]
```

so, you can use URLs like:

```
www.company.com/find/some-text
```

going directly to:

```
www.company.com/result.php?find=some-text
```

niceUrls are better for SEO :)

Answer (score 0):

Add another unique field to the database that will hold the **slug** that you will use for the page, and use that instead.